# How to insert another element into TreeMap value as a List

Tags: java, data-structures

so im still learning about Java mapping and just wondering is it possible to insert another element into TreeMap value as a List? So here's my code:

```
TreeMap<String,List<Integer>> myTree = new TreeMap<>();

String info = "Andi 20";
Integer extra = 100;

String[] temp = info.split(" ");
myTree.put(temp[0], Collections.singletonList(Integer.parseInt(temp[1])));  // {Andi : [20]}
```

**how to insert another element (for example : Integer extra) into a list of value? so the output will look like this :**

```
// {Andi : [20,100]}
```

if it possible, maybe can you give the detail about the time complexity too?? it will help me a lot

Thank you everyone...

Comment: Try: `myTree.get("Andi").add(100)`.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the list then try: `myTree.put(temp[0], List.of(Integer.parseInt(temp[1]),extra));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the `List` implementation you're using supports `add`, of course you can add additional elements.

**But**, you're using `Collections#singletonList`, which by definition does not allow any modifications (the `singleton` collections utilities return immutable implementations). Just use `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.

```java
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("foo", new ArrayList<>());
map.get("foo").add(1);
map.get("foo").add(2);
```

The time complexity for `get` and `put` are in the `TreeMap` documentation:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

The time complexity of `map.get("foo").add(1)` is log(n), because `ArrayList#add` is constant-time.

You can make use of `Map#computeIfAbsent` to handle initializing the `List`:

```java
map.computeIfAbsent("foo", key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(1);
```

**Note** that `computeIfAbsent` is preferable to `putIfAbsent` in any case where `new` is used, because `computeIfAbsent` avoids an unnessary allocation when the key already exists in the map.

Comment: Ahh got it thank you.. but quick question.. what time complexity to declare another Arraylist like that and add number to map again? is it O(n)?

Comment: `ArrayList` offers constant-time `add`, thanks to the amortized cost of allocating and expanding the underlying array. Other `List` implementations will have different characteristics -- all members of the collection framework detail their time complexity in the javadocs :)